# ckeditor отрезает форматирование текста

Tags: php, codeigniter, ckeditor

прикрутил ckeditor в code igniter, но при отправке на сервер все стили обрезаются кроме текста, который не был форматирован. Так же прикрутил ckeditor на голый проект, но там все работает нормально форматирование текста не обрезается. В чем проблема?

Comment: заметил, что code igniter удаляет css из textarea или input

Comment: Ну это защита, чтобы никто плохой скрипт не смог разместить.

Comment: А, как отключить ее?

Answer (score 0):

разобрался, в config.php, $config['global_xss_filtering'] = TRUE; Установить в False